# How may I calculate free energy using PySCF?

Tags: computational-chemistry, thermodynamics, pyscf

I want to calculate the thermodynamic parameters for a single molecule at a certain temperature. How may I do it with PySCF?

Comment: +1 and welcome to our community! Thanks for contributing your question here and we hope to see much more of you in the future !!! Just **please keep in mind** that we try to enforce high standards in our questions, so [in the original version of your question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/revisions/10393/1) before I edited it, the first letter of the title should have had a capital letter, and the word "i" is meant be capitalized whenever you're writing anything (not just on this site). Your question also had `pySCF` in the title but `PySCF` in the body. We want posts to look good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example in which the Gibbs free energy was calculated at 298.15 K was given [here](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/blob/master/examples/hessian/10-thermochemistry.py) by the lead author of PySCF:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# Author: Qiming Sun <osirpt.sun@gmail.com>
#

'''
Thermochemistry analysis based on nuclear Hessian.
'''

from pyscf import gto
from pyscf.hessian import thermo

# First compute nuclear Hessian.
mol = gto.M(
    atom = '''O    0.   0.       0
              H    0.   -0.757   0.587
              H    0.    0.757   0.587''',
    basis = '631g')

mf = mol.RHF().run()
hessian = mf.Hessian().kernel()

# Frequency analysis
freq_info = thermo.harmonic_analysis(mf.mol, hessian)
# Thermochemistry analysis at 298.15 K and 1 atmospheric pressure
thermo_info = thermo.thermo(mf, freq_info['freq_au'], 298.15, 101325)

print('Rotation constant')
print(thermo_info['rot_const'])

print('Zero-point energy')
print(thermo_info['ZPE'   ])

print('Internal energy at 0 K')
print(thermo_info['E_0K'  ])

print('Internal energy at 298.15 K')
print(thermo_info['E_tot' ])

print('Enthalpy energy at 298.15 K')
print(thermo_info['H_tot' ])

print('Gibbs free energy at 298.15 K')
print(thermo_info['G_tot' ])

print('Heat capacity at 298.15 K')
print(thermo_info['Cv_tot'])
```

I found that by searching "free energy PySCF" in Google.